# launch method at certain position of videoview

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

is there a way to launch a method at a certain position of a video playing in a videoview?

only thing that comes in my mind is something like:

```
while(ture)
{
    if(videoview.getCurrentPosition==Position)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a high level, that's pretty much what you're going to wind up with.

From an efficiency standpoint, what you suggest is not going to work well. Something like this will have much less impact on the device:

```
Runnable thePollingLogic=new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    if (yourVideoView.getCurrentPosition()>=theMagicPosition) {
      // do something
    }

    yourVideoView.postDelayed(this, 1);
}
```

This will check your position, then not run again for ~1 millisecond. All you need to do is call `thePollingLogic.run()` once you have started your video playback, and later call `yourVideoView.removeCallbacks(thePollingLogic)` when you no longer need the polling loop.